# Downloading basic Linux commands

Tags: linux, installation, expr

I have a basic Linux distribution on a router. I'd like to install libmodbus to handle some modbus controls locally. However, the Linux distribution lacks the expr command. When I run ./configure to install the package, I get a bunch of errors like: `as_echo: eval: line 1: expr: not found` 
Is there a way that I can install the expr command?

Comment: If you lack something as basic as `expr`, you probably don't have functional build tools. I'd suggest you look up your router and how to install packages on it, and see what packages are available. You probably have `busybox` already which may provide `expr` if you symlink to it, but embedded routers don't come with `gcc` so you won't get far

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

It's best to say the name of the distro. Otherwise, expr is part of the coreutils package which can be downloaded in its purest form from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/

Depending on the distro, you may search for deb or rpm packages ready to install.